# Why can't I convert these hexadecimals into utf-8?

Tags: unicode, binary, hex

Hexadecimals: `0xe0 0x3e 0x38 0x2e 0x7e 0x63 0x78 0x66`

HEX: e0 => DEC: 224

HEX: 3e => DEC: 62

*and so on*.

If I convert each of these hexadecimals to a decimal and look up the decimal in the "unicode table". I get the first two hexadecimals to be equal to:

[E0 = unicode symbol: 'à'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuHfg.png)  and [3E = unicode symbol: '>'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcAHs.png)

This is fine, so why can't that online website decode convert the hexadecimals when I am able to do so manually!?

https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-hexadecimal-to-utf8

[image: hex-to-utf8 conversion error]

Comment: The converter expects the hex representation of UTF-8 bytes. That’s not the same as looking up Unicode code points by their hex notation.

Answer (score 2):

Those bytes do not represent UTF-8 encoding.  `0xE0` in UTF-8 encoding must be followed by two bytes with bit 7 set and bit 6 clear (10xxxxxx<sub>2</sub>).  `0x3e` is not valid, hence your "invalid continuation byte" error message.

The multi-byte sequence `0xC3 0xA0` represents `à` in UTF-8.  Try the following instead:

```
0xc3 0xa0 0x3e 0x38 0x2e 0x7e 0x63 0x78 0x66
```

Recommended reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

The hex sequence you showed is not valid UTF-8, it is actually [ISO-8859-1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (Latin-1) or [Windows-1252](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) instead.

In both of those encodings, the hex sequence `0xe0 0x3e 0x38 0x2e 0x7e 0x63 0x78 0x66` represents the same character sequence `à>8.~cxf`

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @JohnLief like Mark said, the hex sequence you showed does not represent valid UTF-8. `à` is not encoded as `0xE0` in UTF-8. The Latin codepages are very commonly used, so I looked at them and the hex sequence in those codepages exactly match the Unicode characters you are expecting.